# Google insights tool errors for google captcha and youtube embed

Tags: optimization, seo, google-website-optimizer

I am working on website optimization and website speed, my all code is optimized very well, but i have problem in google insights tool, this tool show lot of errors because of one google captcha and one youtube video is embedded, i want google insights to ignore external domain errors and focus on main website assets and content only.

Already optimized the main content and assets.

Answer (score 0):

I'd remove the youtube embedded video and google captcha, cache / purge everything, and then run the insights tool again. That should eliminate those 2 issues and show you if you got other ones.

I'd also suggest taking their recommendations with a grain of salt. There is another tool that you should use https://www.thinkwithgoogle.com/feature/testmysite/ which will test the mobile speed - and that's the one that matters more.